# "with query" vs "temp table" performance wise

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Query performance wise which option is better of the two 1) with query or 2) temp table

1)

```
 with table_map as ( select * from t1 where x=y),
    select col1, sum(col) from table_map group by 1
    union all
    select col2, sum(col) from table_map group by 1
    union all
    select col3, sum(col) from table_map group by 1
```

2)

```
 create temp table tmp_details as (select * from t1 where x=y) 
select col1, sum(col) from tmp_details group by 1
union all
select col2, sum(col) from tmp_details group by 1
union all
select col3, sum(col) from tmp_details group by 1
```

Comment: You would need to try them, but I would expect the CTE to perform better because it does not have the overhead of creating a table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I was assuming temp table is saved to the DB while the CTE will be in memory. So if the in memory dataset is too huge, would the temp table perform better ?

Comment: . . The CTE could overflow onto disk.  The issue is the overhead of a table.  On the other hand, part of that overhead includes statistics on things like table size, which can be used to make the query more efficient.

Comment: I believe one of the gotchas here is that you're not joining, so you will not take advantage of the SORTKEY that you can apply to a TEMPORARY table to help with that. Here you're grouping by "1", but if you are grouping by a column, the SORTKEY should also help. 
This answer is specific to Redshift - I see there is the amazon-redshift tag there, but it is not mentioned any specific flavour in the text.